# How to get back memory after overwriting object

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need to add very much data to a datagridview. Before I have no memory left, I want to use the DGV (e.g. save the rows in a file) and overwrite it. Why don't I get back my memory? I tried already dgv.rows.clear(), dgv.dispose() dgv = new dgv. But nothing helped, the amount of used memory kept beeing the same (I watched it on the ressources Monitor in the Task-Manager). What can I do?
Best regards,
Jan

Comment: Once there are no more references to an object (such as when you clear the rows of the DGV), the memory is marked as available to be reclaimed. It is not released immediately (so you shouldn't expect Task Manager to show more available memory), but it will be reused if it is needed. In other words, you shouldn't need to worry.

Comment: Ok, but the memory is not available immediatly. If I start the programm and pause it after clearing the rows, I have to wait a moment to commence the programm. Otherwise the memory runs full and the programm breaks up.